# JQ using not with IN does not work or have any effect?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

This code works as expected:

```
jq --argjson BL ${BL} '.rows[] | select(.cells[] | .value | IN($BL[]))
```

It returns a list of elements that contain a value in $BL

I want to return all those that are not in $BL, so I use | not

It returns the exact same result as without the | not, it seems to make no difference.

```
jq --argjson BL ${BL} '.rows[] | select(.cells[] | .value | IN($BL[]) | not)
```

using the following retuned nothing at all

```
jq --argjson BL ${BL} '.rows[] | select(.cells[] | .value | IN($BL[]|not))
```

is there a simple thing I'm missing with using IN with NOT?

for reference $BL is and array on email address, trying to make an api call and return all elements that don't have an email listed in $BL

Comment: Please be sure you're providing a [mre]. If we need to build our own data to test your expression, fewer people will work on your problem, or at least will provide _tested_ solutions. (To the extent you can make the expression the simplest possible thing that lets you showcase the problem, that can also make the data needed to test it shorter/simpler/easier).

Comment: ...and btw, I think you want `--argjson BL "$BL"`, unless this code is only intended for people using zsh; without the quotes it'll misbehave on more POSIX-y shells when your data contains whitespace (or glob characters in a shell with `nullglob` or `failglob` enabled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `select` receives a series of boolean values, one for each item in the `.cells` array. Using `not` inverts all of them, which means if you had a mixed set of boolean values, it would still be mixed, and in either case `select` would take those being evaluated to `true`.

The solution is to use `any` or `all` to [aggregate](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#any%2Cany%28condition%29%2Cany%28generator%3Bcondition%29) these boolean values. Without any sample data, I assume you are looking for

```
.rows[] | select(any(.cells[]; .value | IN($BL[])) | not)
```